# --header-html on wkhtmltopdf is above the display area

Tags: php, html, css, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I'm running on wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt) with a windows 11 system.

So, i'm trying to display a header from html file using the --header-html param and my header is only an image. I can see it displayed above the pdf but it won't go down even with a margin-top.

So, here is the code that i run to get the issue on php:

```
$snappy = new Snappy_PDF();
$snappy->setBinary("\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\"");
$snappy->setOption('page-size', 'A4');
$snappy->setOption('enable-local-file-access', true);
$snappy->setOption('header-html', 'http://localhost/bo_test/resources/views/library/header/header.blade.php');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
echo $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html);
```

and here is the header.blade.php:

```
<bloc name='header_3' type='header' >
<img src='C:\wamp64\www\bo_test\public\storage\saderBanner.png' style='width: 100%; margin-top: 500px;' name='header_3_image'>
</bloc>
```

I want the image to go on the top of the pdf and not above.
image
It's hard to see but there is an image, we can see a bit of it on the top.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the fix, i added an option to snappy_PDF:

```
$snappy->setOption('margin-top', '30mm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the height of your header to a fixed height.

```
html, body {
    min-height: 200px
}
```